# How to know what youtube is playing through my android application?

Tags: android, youtube

I want know what youtube is playing through my application.What should I do??
My app will be just like popup dialog app (floating application) and when I am playing any youtube videos,I want to know its youtube video url.

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding how you are playing YouTube videos in your app. I am assuming you are using a WebView? If so, I recommend using the following code in your app to get the url.

```
String getUrl = webView.getUrl();
myTextView.setText(getUrl);
```

or

```
myTextView.setText(webview.getUrl());
```

Comment: No I am not playing youtube videos in my application. I want to know from youtube app through my application.